# Counting Number Of Times Page Has Loaded In Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, count, survey, qualtrics

I am super new to javascript, but I have searched around for this and have not found exactly what I need.

In my Qualtrics survey, I want to record how many times a participant loads a certain page. They will have the opportunity to click "back" and review the previous page as many times as they want and I just want a simple count for this. It would be also great if I could count how many times they click the "back" button, but that seems overly complicated. So just a simple total number of times a particular page loaded would be great!

So far my code is something like this, but again, I have no idea what I'm doing:

```
var n = Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('n');
n = n + 1;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('n', n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the embedded variable n = 0 in your survey flow. Add your code to the addOnload function so it executes each time the page loads.  n will come in as a string, so convert it to an integer.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var n = parseInt("${e://Field/n}");
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("n", n+1);
});
```